# Insert array column query builder laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel and I want to insert an array to a column but it gives me this error
I do not why

here is my query

```
        DB::table('cart_product')->insert([
          ['product_id' => $request->product_id,'quantity' => $request->quantity, 'cart_id' => \Auth::user()->cart()->get()->first()->id, 'color_id' => $request->color, 'total_price' => $productPrice, 'specification' => $request->specification]
          , ]);
```

and here is model

```
class CartProduct extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;
  protected $guarded = ['id'];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
  protected $table = 'cart_product';
  protected $casts = ['specification' => 'array'];
  }
}
```

and error is for this

```
$request->specification
```

here is a dd of this

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "4"
  1 => "7"
  2 => "8"
  3 => "9"
]
```

gives me this error

> Array to string conversion

Comment: I did it the last part of my question

Comment: can you show the table structure of this model?

Comment: is the specification json type?

Comment: If this is an array than you can save this field as json in your database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casts only work when you use Eloquent Models to execute the queries. When you use the Query Builder directly, your casts are not executed, so you are trying to bind an array to a MySQL query.

Either manually `json_encode` the value:

```
DB::table('cart_product')->insert([
    ['specification' => \json_encode($request->specification)]
]);
```

Or use the eloquent model:

```
CartProduct::create([
    'specification' => $request->specification,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Your Array to string**

```
DB::table('cart_product')->insert([[
 'product_id' => $request->product_id,
 'quantity' => $request->quantity,
 'cart_id' => \Auth::user()->cart()->get()->first()->id,
 'color_id' => $request->color, 
 'total_price' => $productPrice, 
 'specification' => '[4, 7, 8, 9]'
]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `DB` then you have to user `json_encode` to save array in your database

```
DB::table('cart_product')->insert([
          [
          'product_id' => $request->product_id, 
          'quantity' => $request->quantity,
          'cart_id' => \Auth::user()->cart()->get()->first()->id, 
          'color_id' => $request->color,
          'total_price' => $productPrice,
          'specification' => json_encode($request->specification) // add json_enocde here
          ]
          , ]);
```